# python incorrect size with getsizeof() and .nbytes with nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, size

I apologise if this is a duplicate issue, but I've been having some issues with `.nsize` and `sys.getsizeof()`.

In particular, I have a **list which contains numpy arrays**, each array is a 3D representation of an image (row, column, RGB) and each of these images have different dimensions.
There are over 4000 images, and this may increase in the future, as I plan to use them for machine learning.

When I use .nsize with one image, I get the correct size, but when I try to evaluate the whole lot, I get an incorrect size:

```
# size of image 1 in bytes
print("size of first image: %d bytes" % images[0].nbytes)

# size of all images in bytes
print("total size of all images: %d bytes" % images.nbytes)
```

Result:

```
size of first image: 60066 bytes

total size of all images: 36600 bytes
```

Are the only ways around this to either loop through all the images or change to a monstrous 4D array instead of a list of 3D arrays? Is there another function which better evaluates size for this kind of nested setup?

I'm running Python 3.6.7.

Comment: Focus on shape and dtype.  The other measures don't help you understand. And don't give us a massive display of the data.

Comment: Many, if not all, machine learning tools, assume the images have the same shape.    They will raise errors if you try to use a list or object dtype array with diverse shapes.   Both lists and object arrays contain pointers to arrays elsewhere in memory.  So any size measure of the container just sees the pointers (e.g. 8 byte integers).

Comment: @hpaulj I would have avoided including that data but someone asked for it. I'll remove it now.

Comment: @hpaulj as it happens I guess that second comment of yours answers my question as to 'why' it is happening, so thanks for that. I understand that better now. I'm not going to close this yet as I'm looking for solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `images.dtype`. What does it return? If it's `dtype('O')`, that explains your problem: `images` is not a list, but is instead a Numpy array of type `object`, which is generally a Bad Idea™️. Technically, it'll be an 1D array holding a bunch of 3D arrays.

Numpy arrays are best suited to use with numerical data. They're flexible enough to hold arbitrary Python objects, but it greatly impairs both their functionality and their efficiency. Unless you have a clear reason why in mind, you should generally just use a plain Python list `[]` in these situations.

You may actually be best off converting `images` to a 4D array, as this is the only way that `images.nbytes` will work correctly. You can't do this if your images are all different sizes, but given that they all have the same shape `(x, y, z)` it's actually pretty straightforward:

```
images = np.array([a for a in images])
```

Now `images.shape` will be `(n, x, y, z)`, where `n` is the total number of images. You can access the 3D array that represents the `i`th image by just indexing `images`:

```
image_i = images[i]
```

Alternatively, you can convert `images` to a normal Python list:

```
images = images.to_list()
```

If you don't want to bother with any of those conversions, you can always get the size of all the subarrays via iteration:

```
totalsize = sum(arr.nbytes for arr in images)
```

Comment: images.dtype returns "object", which I'm guessing is what you said. Even though I created it as a list, I guess it changed type when I started importing arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what you propose with making it a 4D array does theoretically pose a problem though. If I import an image larger than the previous one into the 4D array, I'd probably get an error and have to pad previous images so it all fits. I'd then have to reverse this process every time I access the image. Seems like a huge hassle just so I can gauge the 'weight' of my dataset.